# Limit only parts of a Regular Expression not the whole expression itself?

Tags: regex, wildcard, digits, maxlength

so I have an input field where the client can type in numbers from 1-10 in length with a wildcard with at least 1 number as prefix. (* is not allowed, while 1* would be)

The Wildcard can be set in the middle of the string, BUT the overall max length of the expression is 10.
At this point I received this result by the following expression:

```
^([ ,;]?(?=.{1,10}$)((\d{1,9})(\*?)(\d{0,9}?))[ ,;]?)$
```

Now the problem. As you can see in the expression, seperators SPACE, COMMA & SEMI-COLON are allowed at the beginning or at the end of a string, because the client can input multiple numbers in that combination. `[ ,;]?`

But he can't because of the max length of 10 `(?=.{1,10}$)`.
On the other hand, if I remove the max length limit, then you can input one number longer than 10 (exactly max 19 characters right now) `123456789*123456789` -> would be allowed without the limitation.

Is there any way to limit the expression that way, that the character length in between the seperators must be 10 absolute MAX length, but overall the max length can longer to input more numbers?

Comment: Can you add an example or two (for each showing the desired result)?

Comment: @CarySwoveland you can see examples here [link](https://regex101.com/r/nUKCMi/2)

Comment: After finally clearing the cobwebs I revised my answer (suggesting `^\d[\d*]{0,9}(?:[ ,;]\d[\d*]{0,9})*$`) but then noticed that @JvdV had suggested essentially the same thing (in "EDIT3"), so I deleted my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe:

```
^(?:\d(?=\d*\*?\d*(?:[ ,;]|$))[\d*]{0,9}(?:[ ,;]|$))+$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/M7XIDV/1)

Since you want to start a number with at least a single digit, the following would match;

- `^` - Start of string ancor.
- `(?:` - Open 1st non-capture group.

  - `\d` - Match a single digit.
  - `(?=` Open positive lookahead.

    - `\d*\*?\d*` - Any amount of digits, an optional wildcard, and again any amount of digits (to only allow a single wildcard).
    - `(?:` - Open nested 2nd non-capture group.

      - `[ ,;]|$` - Match any of the characters in the character class ***or*** then end of the string.
      - `)` - Close 2nd non-capture group.
    - `)` - Close positive lookahead.
  - `[\d*]{0,9}` - Match 0-9 characters from the character class (digits or wildcards).
  - `(?:` - Open 3rd non-capturing group.

    - `[ ,;]|$` - Match any of the characters in the character class ***or*** then end of the string.
    - `)` - Close 3rd non-capturing group.
  - `)` - Close 1st non-capturing group.
- `+` - Repeat 1st non-capturing group at least once.
- `$` - End string ancor.

---

***EDIT1***: The above would allow for a trailing comma, semi-colon or space. If you want to avoid that you could use:

```
^(?:\d(?=\d*\*?\d*[ ,;])[\d*]{0,9}[ ,;])*\d(?=\d*\*?\d*$)[\d*]{0,9}$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/M7XIDV/3)

---

***EDIT2***: The above would allow only a single wildcard per number. If your intention was such that multiple should be allowed (but simply not after one another, you could try:

```
^(?:\d(?!.*\*\*.*[ ,;])[\d*]{0,9}[ ,;])*\d(?!.*\*\*.*$)[\d*]{0,9}$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/M7XIDV/4)

---

***EDIT3***: If for some reason you decide you **do** want to allow consecutive wildcards (but still start with atleast a single digit), you could opt for:

```
^(?:\d[\d*]{0,9}[ ,;])*\d[\d*]{0,9}$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/M7XIDV/5)

Comment: this looks like the perfect solution!
Tried many cases and worked great so far - thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: your edit expression has an error because with that you're allowed to type in multiple wildcards behind each other.

The first one handles this error fine, but as you mentioned it allows trailing seperators.

Comment: @EXTSY, you were correct. I reworked it so it should stop doing so. Btw, this would also only allow a single wildcard max. Is this your intention?

Comment: Thank you for your edit! At first it was the intention just to use a single wildcard per number, but after thinking about it a bit, indeed it makes sense to have the ability to use multiple wildcards instead I think. So I'm very happy you gave me both solutions here. :)

Comment: If you are changing your mind about these wildcards you might want to think about using consecutive wildcards. If that is the case, I have even added an option which does exactly that (but forces a number to start with a digit still)